# How to increment a MySQL database row value

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL database with a table called `chapters`.

I have a column called `chapter_number` which is an Integer data type and is NOT auto increment as I have another field which uniquely identifies the row.

Upon insertion to this table I would like the value of the `chapter_number` column to be the previous row's `chapter_number` incremented by 1 (+1).

The purpose of this is to ensure that every time a chapter is added, the right ordering takes place.

How could I achieve this in PHP?

Here is an example of what I mean?

Table structure:

[image]

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO chapters VALUES (?,?,?,?)');
$stmt->execute(array('','title', '2015-04-03', 'chapter 1 body'));
```

What would I put for the first parameter ^

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html `INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=c+1;

UPDATE table SET c=c+1 WHERE a=1;` based on your *"Upon **insertion** to this table"*

Comment: If you delete a row, the id for that row cannot be re-used until the table is reset?  So, if you delete row 2 and then insert a new row, the auto increment of the id will store chapter_id =4 in row 2.

Comment: *"I have already found a way of re ordering the rows if any get deleted thanks to this"* - I wouldn't have posted my first linked comment. INSERT and UPDATE are *two different animals* altogether. ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii-  Not too sure what you mean. I'm struggling to get my head around what value would I actually put in the query for the `chapter_number` column if I want it to be the value of the previous row + 1?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure if by your edit you meant if you already solved the problem.

Comment: No, the edit suggests that I have found a way to re order the table if any rows get deleted, I still however have the problem of how to insert the value in the first place. The edit is aimed at @Dreamwalker's comment

Comment: *Hm...*, maybe you can do something with `mysqli_insert_id()`. I don't know how to do it, but that function tells me it would probably help you accomplish what you wish to achieve.

Comment: @Fred-ii- That only works for auto generated id's such as auto increments, my `chapter_number` is not an auto increment field

Comment: Removed the edit as it may confuse people into thinking I solved this question

Comment: Something just came to mind. What I used to do to mimic an AI, was to first query the table (SELECT) and assigned a variable to the said column such as `$var = $row['column'] +1;`  then I would then include that in an insert. Now, it's been a while since I've last used that and am unsure if I can find it again; I'm talking years. Another method would be to use a trigger. You can base yourself on the answer below, which is basically the same thing, just assign a variable to it.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT max(chapter_number) + 1 as total FROM table;
```

This would also allow you to later on have chapters assigned to multiple books by symply adding a where clause

The following example is how this syntax would look

```
insert into table_one (greeting_column, name_column)
SELECT 
     'hello',
     (SELECT max(chapter_number) + 1 as total FROM table)
```

Comment: This is selecting not inserting. Doesn't answer the question

Comment: It does answer the question. The provided query can be run as a subquery to achieve the correct result.